# Power supply with incorrect voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, capacitor, sound

I have found that the voltage at the output of this power supply has the wrong values.

Where +-12 V should come out, it was oscillating between 16 and 17 V, but I managed to correct the oscillation by changing the electrolytic capacitors near the bridge, but still having 4 V more than expected.

The transformer is delivering normally the 12+12 V.

[image: power supply diagram]

Comment: Does it drop if you load the output? Looks like an unregulated 50/60 Hz supply.

Comment: It is a power supply that works at 110v-220v 60Hz. The transformer outside the board is fine, the board without the capacitors also works, but when I put them in, the voltage rises and R162 and R163 get too hot.

Comment: Has the output ever been 12V under load? Because a 12 VAC output would have DC voltage of about 16V to 17V under little or no load.

Comment: In context: this is the power supply for a Home Theater. When I remove the electrolytics, it works normal, but when I put it on, the TDA2030 gets too hot even in standby, in addition to the two resistors having already burned once too.

Comment: I went to compare the voltages with the manufacturer's project, and where I should have these -12V and +12V, there's -16V and +16v

Comment: TDA2030 takes +-18 V so it should not heat up, but the design has very poor margins.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where I could be wrong?

This is the [service manual of the device containing the schematics](https://www.electronica-pt.com/esquema/audio/philco-pht510-20683/)

Comment: That’s a toy. Replace all electrolytic capacitors and the TDA2030 heating up. If that doesn’t help, it’s e-waste.

Comment: I'll try to do that and then come back to say if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your +12V and -12V rails are completely unregulated.  They will float up to a higher voltage when unloaded.  The more load you put on, the lower the voltage will drop and the more ripply the DC will be.

If you reduce the capacitors, the voltage will drop, but the ripple will be worse.

Comment: So for this reason, analyzing performance of this PSU is dependent on operation of the rest of the circuit (it can't be tested out-of circuit.)  If the two resistors have already burned once, then this is indicating a problem with the TDA-side of things.

Comment: It really might be on the audio side. Already burned the two resistors and a capacitor, and also the five external outputs are not working, only the sub that works for a while

Answer (score 0):

The transformer secondaries are 12Vrms. Rectified provides 16.8V peak minus the diode drops. The mains voltage will fluctuate.

What you are measuring is correct.